# AFNetworking SSL Pinning Expired Certificates

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking-2

How do you update expired ssl certificates if ssl pinning is used on ios apps?  It seems like only an app update would enable updating the certificate but then users who don't update the app will not receive this update.

Answer (score 12):

The key is to understand [the possible values](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.2.0/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.h#L26-L30) for `AFSecurityPolicy`'s `pinningMode`.

`AFSSLPinningModeCertificate` means that the certificate provided by the server must match exactly one of the pinned certificates, which by default are the certificates in your app bundle. This is the mode you are currently using.

`AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` means that the certificate provided by the server must contain the same public key as one of the certificates pinned by your app.

If you use `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` and renew (update) your server certificate with the same keypair, your iOS app will continue to work without modification.

Comment: Are you sure `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` means that the server must have been *signed by* the same key, as opposed to having the certificate contain the same public key as the reference one (which would generally make more sense)?

Comment: @Bruno Thanks, I've amended the explanation to make it clearer.

Comment: No worries, good answer anyway, I was actually just looking at the bottom of the file you linked to, it said indeed "*Validate host certificates against public keys of pinned certificates.*".

Comment: what about if you have to change the key upon renewing the certificate?

Comment: If you change the key, the certificate won't match for either pinning mode, and you'll have to get your users to update the app.

Comment: Is it true that `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` does not check the expiration date of the bundled certificate? I'm having trouble determining if this is the case as you seem to have indicated.

Comment: One would assume so – the idea with public key pinning is that new certificates can be issued and deployed to a server, and old clients continue to function.

Answer (score 0):

To address the second part of the question, yes users with old versions will be locked out.

To lower the impact, a common strategy is to include the new certificate alongside the soon to be expired certificate. This gives users a few 'buffer' versions they can be on and still have access after the changeover.