# Handling SSL certificates as they are renewed on the server

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate

I have a cert signed by a CA (Geotrust) on my server. I have the same cert installed in my app. I compare the two certs in URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:. But I was notified by my hosting service that I need to 'renew' the cert each year. That creates a new and different cert for me to handle in the app. Since the certs are not self-signed, do I need to embed the cert in the app for comparison with the cert as it comes from the server or does iOS's SSL handling take care of the challenge for me. Maybe I can just use server trust without looking at the cert?

Comment: Can you clarify whether your client is determining if the server is correct, or if the server is determining if the client is correct?

Comment: See this answer on SSL pinning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055153/afnetworking-ssl-pinning-expired-certificates it may help

Answer (score 0):

> I have the same cert installed in my app.

Why?

> I compare the two certs in URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler.

Why?

What you should be doing is comparing the subjectDN. That's what the signer is verifying. It's all you need.

> Maybe I can just use server trust without looking at the cert?

It sounds like you're trying to do the correct thing and add an authorization step. Relying on 'server trust' just gives you authentication, i.e. the subject DN is who he says he is. Authorization checks whether that DN is authorised to use this part of the application. But you don't need to check the entire certificate for that.